# How to disable hover on product woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a website with WordPress with a theme named star Bella-electronics with woocommerce integrated and I want to disable the hover effects on products.

I don't have theme settings to disable hover, I try it to find the class with hover but I don't found it.

Site:https://trofez-shop.ro/product-category/trofee-si-cupe-personalizate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below CSS.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover .secondary-image, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:hover .secondary-image{ display: none !important; }
.product-button-hover { display: none !important; opacity: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: This didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css in your theme style.css

```
li.product:hover .product-button-hover {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work.